# HowTo get a Tag Cloud on gitweb?

Tags: git, tags, gitweb

How can I configure a Tag Cloud view to my gitweb project list?

I saw an example of this on the git repo http://repo.or.cz/ but i'am not sure how to configure this on my own gitweb installation.

Is there an example gitweb_config.perl for this?

Answer (score 0):

The [`gitweb.perl` script documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7fe683480124239ec0ab555c9b529e4c54707d7b/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L444-L453) (included in the [git repo itself](https://github.com/git/git/)) does mention:

> Allow gitweb scan project content tags of project repository, and display the popular Web 2.0-ish "tag cloud" near the projects list.
>   Note that this is something COMPLETELY different from the normal Git tags.
>
> gitweb by itself can show existing tags, but it does not handle tagging itself; you need to do it externally, outside gitweb.
>   The format is described in [`git_get_project_ctags()` subroutine](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7fe683480124239ec0ab555c9b529e4c54707d7b/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L2889-L2896).
>   You may want to install the [**`HTML::TagCloud` Perl module**](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TagCloud/lib/HTML/TagCloud.pm%2a) to get a pretty tag cloud instead of just a list of tags.

[`git_get_project_ctags()` subroutine](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7fe683480124239ec0ab555c9b529e4c54707d7b/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L2889-L2896):

> supported formats:
>
> - `$GIT_DIR/ctags/<tagname>` file (in 'ctags' subdirectory)
>
>   - if its contents is a number, use it as tag weight,
>   - otherwise add a tag with weight 1
> - `$GIT_DIR/ctags` file, each line is a tag (with weight 1)
>     the same value multiple times increases tag weight
> - `gitweb.ctag` multi-valued repo config variable

Comment: Thx now i have a list of tags in my gitweb. I'am waiting if my hoster can install that Tag Cloud Perl Module package for me.